# При наведении на ромб появляется не переведенная подсказка "moderator"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Когда я навожу курсор на ромб возле никнейма модератора, я вижу следующее:

> [image]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотреть [самостоятельно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky).

Answer (score 2):

<s>Проверил, все еще не переведено.</s> Теперь переведено. Очевидно, что всплывающая подсказка должна гласить:

> модератор